# Aligning 4 figures

Tags: floats

I use [amcs](https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/?action=guide) template. 
I would like to align 4 figures to same size so the first two will be in same row. However, there is a slight change in the starting position and sizes as well as caption locations. How can I fix it?
[image]

This is my code:

```
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}

\documentclass{amcs}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics [scale=0.6]{Figure5Graph1.png}
    \caption{DS1: PKsd saklsajlslak lska dfkjlsdkfj fdgdffjdsl lkllk sdfsfdfs dsgsd}
    \label{fig:DS1}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics [scale=0.6]{Figure6Graph2.png}
    \caption{DS2: Ksd saklsajlslak lska dfkjlsdkfj fdgdffjdsl lkllk sdfsfdfs dsgsd}
    \label{fig:DS2}
\end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics [scale=0.6]{Figure7Graph3.png}
    \caption{DS3: Ksd saklsajlslak lska dfkjlsdkfj fdgdffjdsl lkllk sdfsfdfs dsgsd}
    \label{fig:DS3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics [scale=0.6]{Figure8Graph4.png}
    \caption{DS4: Ksd saklsajlslak lska dfkjlsdkfj fdgdffjdsl lkllk}
    \label{fig:DS4}
\end{figure}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You could use the `subfig` package

Comment: Thanks @DRi, can you please elaborate, what do I have to change in my code?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{subfig}`in your preamble and read the package notice to know how tio use it.

Comment: If you want to be sure, all the images are the same size, it is saver not to use `scale=0.6` but to specify the with width e.g. `width=.45\textwidth`

Answer (score 4):

Add `\usepackage{subfig}` in your preamble and in your text, use something like:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfloat[subtitle of subfigure a]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{figures/subfig_a}}\qquad
\subfloat[subtitle of subfigure b]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{figures/subfig_b}}\\
\subfloat[subtitle of subfigure c]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{figures/subfig_c}}\qquad%
\subfloat[subtitle of subfigure d]{\label{fig:d}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{figures/subfig_d}}%
\caption{My beautiful multifigure ((a) subfig a; (b) subfig b; (c) subfig c; (d) subfig d)}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: My figure are in png format when I write the code, I get the following error: Package pdftex.def Error: File `figures/Figure7Graph3.png' not found. ....6\textwidth]{figures/Figure7Graph3.png}}

Comment: You don't need to explicit the extension of your figures.

Comment: I omitted the extensions and still get the following error: File `figures/Figure7Graph3' not found. ...th=0.6\textwidth]{figures/Figure7Graph3}}

Comment: Do you compile with LaTeX or with pdfLaTeX, I suspect the former which uses .ps or .eps file while the later uses .png,.pdf. Did you include `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble ?

Comment: Of course when I wrote `\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{figures/subfig_a}` this meant that the figures are in a folder named figures. If this is not the case, if they are in the same folder as the .tex file, the you should use       `\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{subfig_a}` and so on.

Comment: I didn't use \usepackage{graphicx}. I fixed the above error. But now I get the following: Undefined control sequence. ...cs [width=0.45\linewidth]{Figure6Graph2}}

Comment: Finally, I get the following error: Command \caption@eh already defined. section about errors.\MessageBreak\@ehc}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48117/discussion-between-dri-and-avi).