# Error with subfigure and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

I'm trying to include two TikZ pictures in one figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParabola}
     \caption{Text.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParaboloid}
     \caption{More text.}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here I get the following error message:

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The tikz images are both saved and in the folder TikZ? If yes, then you can use `\subfigure[width=0.5\textwidth][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth,trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip]{TikZ/filename}}´.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337939/aligning-4-figures/337942#337942  . By the way, what is the point of using `subfigure` if you have only one ?   It seems to me that you forgot to include the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Exactly. The program cannot find file:
File `TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParabola' not found. ...mm, clip]{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParabola}}

Comment: @DRi 
Sure, for one figure it doesn't make any sense. Corrected.

Comment: @ingenium. Is the saved image filetyp for example pdf? It should work if the .tex file is at the same level with the TikZ folder.

Comment: @Bobyandbob It is a .tex file. I can include this file in a single figure, so I think it is nothing wrong with the file. And if I add .tex extension, then I get following error message:
Unknown graphics extension: .tex. ...clip]{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParabola.tex}}

Comment: @ingenium. You can try to save it as pdf like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243935/error-using-tikz-externalize-cant-write-md5-file/352732#352732 (it works for me). You can replace \begin{tikz}... with your .tikz file. And then you can use the subfigures...

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for the suggestion, but it should be possible with subfigure.

Comment: You probably want `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParabola}}`.

Comment: But the error is because you're loading the wrong package, you want `\usepackage{subcaption}`, not `\usepackage{subfigure}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

First, `\resizebox` just resizes what it is given, it doesn't look for files anywhere. Hence, if you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParaboloid

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParaboloid}
\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

To actually insert the contents of the `.tex` file, you need `\input` as well:

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParaboloid}}
```

The second is that you've loaded the wrong package for subfloats. The `subfigure` package that you've loaded does not define a `subfigure` environment, it defines a `\subfigure` macro, that is used as `\subfigure[<list entry>][<subcaption>]{<figure>}`. But that package is considered deprecated, so you shouldn't use it.

The syntax you have used is actually defined by the `subcaption` package, so you should replace `\usepackage{subfigure}` with `\usepackage{subcaption}`.

And finally, an empty line signifies a paragraph break, also inside a `figure` environment, so you need to remove the one between the `subfigure` environments, otherwise they will end up one above the other.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParabola}}
     \caption{Text.}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{TikZ/QuadrateResiduenParaboloid}}
     \caption{More text.}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I still get the error message:
[link] (https://w18i.imgup.net/unknown15a9.png)

Comment: @ingenium The first error tells you that you're loading both the `subfigure` and `subcaption` package, and you can't have both. Load *only* `subcaption`, as in my example.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. It works. Thank you very much.